# Pivot Table in R where the value is date

Tags: r, pivot

R newbie here. I need to use one of the columns "Student Status" and make it columns and get the date values associated with that StudentID and StudentStatus.

Here is my original data.

[image: Tabular Data]

This is my desired output.

[image]

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reshape data from long to wide format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/how-to-reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `pivot_wider` function from `tidyr` to do that.

```
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = StudentStatus,
              values_from = StatusDate)
```

Comment: pivot_wider doesn't appear to work currently, unless you grab a developer version of dplyr, but even then has issues: https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr/issues/635

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `dcast` function from the `data.table` package to do this ...

```
# install.packages('data.table')
library(data.table)

# Coerce the data.frame to a data.table.
dt <- data.table(df)

# Cast the data.table ...
dcast(dt, StudentID + City ~ StudentStatus)
#    StudentID           City Dropped Out   Enrolled  Graduated
# 1:         1 Long Beach, CA  12/21/2012  8/21/2011       <NA>
# 2:         2 Long Beach, CA        <NA>  8/21/2011 12/11/2014
# 3:         3 Long Beach, CA        <NA> 11/21/2011  1/21/2016
```

---

**Example data:**

```
df <- data.frame(StudentID = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3),
                City = rep("Long Beach, CA", 6), 
                StudentStatus = c("Enrolled", "Enrolled","Enrolled", "Dropped Out", "Graduated", "Graduated"), 
                StatusDate = c("8/21/2011","8/21/2011","11/21/2011","12/21/2012","12/11/2014","1/21/2016"))
```